# How can I remotely access my office computer?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop

I would like to ask a very basic question. I would appreciate sharing some knowledge on here.

I have two pcs in my office running linux. I checked and their external IP address is the same.

How can I access it from my windows machine at home.

I have the following tools: 
SuperPutty
Visual Studio Code

and Remote Desktop

When I try to access it with that IP address I got rejected (connection refused) 
but actually my ignorance is deeper, since I don't know if they are using the same IP address which computer I am accesing.

Can someone explain me how to do this so that I can work from home with the PCs at work?

Comment: You need to ask your system administrator at work to open ports for you, so the public ip address and port is linked to your workplace pc. Both pc's can be linked by a different port, but an adjustment on the router must be made.

Comment: Your office network as well as your home network are both doing something called NAT (or masquerading). All computers in their respective network appear to have the same IP address when looked at from the outside. When you're talking to your home IP, you are talking to your home router. When talking to your office IP, your talking to your office router (or so). You need to configure either router to forward external connections to a specific computer on its local network, and than establish a connection (e.g. an SSH tunnel) from the other end.

Comment: so the IP refers to the router? How can I access an individual computer?

Comment: If you have VPN access, as stated in the comment of an answer, make VPN first, then use the Internal IP address of the pc you want to connect to, and it should work.

Comment: Do you manage the Office network?  To answer your question above - the IP address is that of the router.  In order to access individual computers behind that router you need to reconfigure the router or you need to make use of third party software and a third party server to route the connections through.

Comment: @LPChip Ok. I ll try. I suppose I can ssh there then but would I need something more for remote desktop? (like some activation in the ubuntu system?)

Comment: @KansaiRobot if you install FreeRDP on your linux, you can use Microsoft Remote Desktop to remote into it, the same way you SSH into it.

Comment: @KansaiRobot - Contact your IT Administrator for specifics on which IP address to use to access the devices in question.  Based on the information provided, we cannot determine that information, anything short of a specific answer won't be very helpful.  **What exactly do you mean by "activation" with regards to the machine running Ubuntu?**

Answer (score -3):

you will need to install third party app like logmein.com or teamviewer to access remote pc. but i feel office pcs are more secure if accessed via official authorised VPN gateway

Comment: I have already a VPN set in my window machine

Comment: what  you have is maybe VPN client. You need to connect to your office VPN server via this client and then you will be able to ssh into linux machine

Comment: ok, but which IP should I use? All computers seem to have the same IP    I read this is the router IP...

Comment: you will need to connect with your office local IT team for this as they will provide every info needed to connect to a VPN server.

Comment: I have my VPN credentials already but this is something like `mycompany.vpn.thecompany.com' . I don't see what this has to do with the actual PC I want to access. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @LPChip +1 - teamviewer is a very practical solution in an SME for occassional use.   Especially one where there is no system administrator.   Of-course the likes of you and me can do better.  Of-course, you've almost got to ask what Linux is doing in that kind of environment!

Comment: This is also what i suggested in my very first answer to use teamviewer.

Comment: this is baseless explanation and everyone can see that what i suggested in my very first answer for which i am being told that it does not provide answer to the question. When same thing was told by different user and it was accepted as answer.